# ggplot2: How to parse a character variable (e.g. x <- ".35") as character, not number, in geom_text label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a figure for publication and wish to annotate it with some beta and p values; the style guidelines of my area dictate that these numbers be formatted without leading zeros (e.g., ".003", not "0.003"). I have run into what seems like a Catch-22; I have extracted beta and p values from my models and done some preprocessing to correctly format them so that they are now characters rather than numeric:

```
fake.beta.vals <- c(".53", ".29", ".14")
fake.p.vals <- c(".034", ".001", ".050")
```

But, when I try to use these values in my figure, `parse = TRUE` turns them back into numeric values, losing the formatting I need.

```
fake.beta.vals <- c(".53", ".29", ".14")
fake.p.vals <- c(".034", ".001", ".050")

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
p <- p + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ Species)
p

len <-length(levels(iris$Species))
vars <- data.frame(expand.grid(levels(iris$Species)))
colnames(vars) <- c("Species")
betalabs <- as.data.frame(fake.beta.vals)
plabs <- as.data.frame(fake.p.vals)
dat <- data.frame(
  x = rep(7, len),
  y = rep(4, len),
  vars,
  betalabs,
  plabs)
dat$fake.beta.vals <- as.factor(dat$fake.beta.vals)
dat$fake.p.vals <- as.factor(dat$fake.p.vals)

p <- p +
  geom_text(
    aes(x     = x,
        y     = y,
        label = paste("list(beta ==",
                      fake.beta.vals,
                      ", italic(p) ==",
                      fake.p.vals,
                      ")"),
        group = NULL),
    size  = 5,
    data  = dat,
    parse = TRUE)
p
```

I have been banging my head against this problem for a while now but adding `as.character()`:

```
        label = paste("list(beta ==",
                      as.character(fake.beta.vals),
                      ", italic(p) ==",
                      as.character(fake.p.vals),
                      ")"),
```

Is obviously also cancelled out by `parse = TRUE`

And adding the function I had previously used to format my values:

```
statformat <- function(val,z){
  sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf(paste("%.",z,"f", sep = ""), val))
}
```

Is even worse:

```
        label = paste("list(beta ==",
                      statformat(fake.beta.vals, 2),
                      ", italic(p) ==",
                      statformat(fake.p.vals, 3),
                      ")"),
```

And just ends up with a mess.

Help?

Comment: +1 for reproducible example. Offhand, for publication figures you could just import the pdf into (e.g.) Inkscape and remove the 0

Comment: In the past, I've used Inkscape to edit my figures; however, historically I've found it to be a pain when reviewers ask to see a variant on a model, etc., and then I have to re-edit all my figures by hand. I would love to have my figures totally scripted so that revisions are less tedious. But I agree Inkscape is an excellent program (open source! yay!)

Comment: Try encasing it using the `I` function. `?I` tells me that it inhibits the interpretation/conversion of objects. It should tell `ggplot2` to take that input literally. e.g. `ggplot(..., label=I(fake.beta.vals), ...`. I cannot test it right now, but I am pretty sure it should work, so I'm just leaving this comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `bquote` to create the labels, then coerce to a character representation using `deparse`

For example

```
# create a list of labels using bquotw
labs <- Map(.beta = fake.beta.vals, 
            .p = fake.p.vals, 
          f = function(.beta,.p) bquote(list(beta == .(.beta), italic(p) == .(.p))))
# coerce to a character representation for parse=TRUE to work within 
# geom_text
dat <- data.frame(
  x = rep(7, len),
  y = rep(4, len),
  vars,
  labels = sapply(labs,deparse))


p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ Species) +
  geom_text(data = dat, aes(x=x,y=y,label=labels), parse=TRUE)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the unnamed function argument in the third position within the arguments to `Map`?  (And thanks for explaining why my efforts with `bquote` came to fail due to the lack of a `deparse` step.)

Comment: @Dwin -- laziness. The function argument is now named appropriately as `f`.

Comment: I wasn't trying to get it named, instead was trying figure out why it even succeeded. I thought it would fail, but perhaps the fact that the first 2 arguments were names something other than `f` allowed it to succeed?

Comment: Brilliant! I had been thinking some of `deparse` but couldn't figure out how to appropriately combine with `parse = TRUE`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After getting back to my computer and re-reading your question, I found that I misinterpreted the question. Trying out the `I` function, I found that it doesn't seem to work with `parse`.

I found a way to get it to work, and this is by encasing your `fake.beta.vals` and `fake.p.vals` with the ` character or the ' character in your call to parse.

```
p <- p +
  geom_text(
    aes(x     = x,
        y     = y,
        label = paste("list(beta ==",
                      "`", fake.beta.vals, "`",
                      ", italic(p) ==",
                      "`", fake.p.vals, "`",
                      ")", 
                      sep=""),
        group = NULL),
    size  = 5,
    data  = dat,
    parse = TRUE)
```

That should work.